# backface-visibilty in rounded corners of a css cube

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm trying a simple css cube and applying rounded corners shows that the box is empty and transparent, applying `backface-visibility: hidden;` makes it like filled with white color and **the question is,** if is there a way to style the appereance of colors and other properties to the behavior of the mentioned property backface-visibility?

**backface-visibility: visible**

[image: backface-visibility: visible;]

***backface-visibility: hidden***

[image: backface-visibility: hidden]

[image: cube gif]

```css
.welcome {
  color:green;
  font-size:36px;
  font-family:cursive;
  text-align:center;
  padding:20px;
}

.* {
    background-color: black;
    
}


h2 {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #666;
  padding: 0.25em;
  text-align:center;
}

div.space3D {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 3em auto 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0,255,0);
  position: relative;
  perspective-origin: center -50%;
  perspective: 300px;
  transform: scale(0.75);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

div.cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(-150px);
  animation-name: gira;
  animation-duration: 15000ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.base {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  transform: translateX(75px) translateY(75px) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-200px);
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

div.cara {
  position: absolute;
  width: 298px;
  height: 298px;
  background-color: #c2ffef;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-radius: 2em;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 298px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(255,150,0,0.25);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  /*backface-visibility:hidden;*/
}


div.cara1 { /* Frente */
  transform: translateZ(150px);
}

div.cara2 { /* Atrás */
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(150px);
}

div.cara3 { /* Izquierda */
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(150px);
}

div.cara4 { /* derecha */
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(150px);
}

div.cara5 { /* abajo */
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(150px);
}

div.cara6 { /* arriba */
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(150px);
}

@keyframes gira {
  0% {
    transform: translateZ(-150px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateZ(-150px) rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Cubo 3D con puro HTML5 y CSS3</h2>

<div class="space3D">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="base"></div>
    <div class="cara cara1">rubik</div>
    <div class="cara cara2"></div>
    <div class="cara cara3"></div>
    <div class="cara cara4"></div>
    <div class="cara cara5"></div>
    <div class="cara cara6"></div>
  </div><!-- termina cubo 3d -->
  
  
</div><!-- termina espacio 3d -->



</body>
</html>
```